# AWS EC2 access only from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a database running on an EC2 instance in a public subnet.

I would like to protect the EC2 instance so it can only be accessed from the lambdas.

I do not want to attach the lambda through an ENI as it is not a scalable solution, due to the ENI that must be created to allow the lambda access to the VPC.

I had in mind to use a NACL and to only allow inbound traffic from the ip range of the AWS lambda service, but I do not know how often AWS could update its IP ranges.

Please any suggestions regarding security issues will be welcomed

Comment: how can you get ip on aws lambda ?

Comment: for what purpose you want to use your ec2 for ?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend running a database in a public subnet -- we keep everything in a private subnet without Internet access for security.

Comment: Using the entire IP range of AWS would not be very secure, since anyone else using AWS would be able to access your EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

Whitelisting AWS Lambda IP range won't work since we don't have any control over the IP range when Lambda is outside the VPC.

If you are keeping the EC2 in a public subnet there is hardly any approach available to restrict to requests only for Lambda unless you put the Lambda function inside the VPC.

If you can use AWS RDS for the database it is now possible to restrict access via IAM (AWS recently introduced this).